# Wandb not initializing on Nvidia Pytorch Image arm64

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, arm64, wandb

I'm having serious problems with wandb on a nVidia pytorch image using arm64 architecture. No info online on how to solve this problem. Cannot even start a project with wandb.init()
[python error]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdgDT.png

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 #!pip install wandb
2 import wandb
----> 3 wandb.init(project='gpt3')

AttributeError: module 'wandb' has no attribute 'init'

Answer (score 0):

It seems wandb hasn't been installed correctly in your case.

Comment: So.. how do I install it correctly ?
Isn’t it pip install Wandb?

Comment: Try installing it as follows: `%pip install wandb` . This way the package should get installed into the current kernel as opposed to the instance of Python that launched the notebook.